# Making MMAP macro with x86 asm

Tags: c, assembly, macros, x86

I am trying to make a macro that takes in a ptr and mmap's argument's then set it accordingly. This is what I have so far:

```
#define MY_MMAP(PTR, ARG1, ARG2, ARG3, ARG4, ARG5, ARG6) \
({              \
int x = 90; \
asm  (          \
    "movl %1, %%eax \n"     \
    "movl %2, %%ebx \n" \
    "movl %3, %%ecx \n" \
    "movl %4, %%edx \n" \
    "movl %5, %%esi \n" \
    "movl %6, %%edi \n" \
    "movl %7, %%ebp \n" \
    "int $0x80 \n"          \
    "movl %%eax, %0"      \
    :"=r" (PTR)     \
    : "eax" (x) ,"ebx" (ARG1), "ecx" (ARG2), "edx" (ARG3), "esi" (ARG4), "edi" (ARG5), "ebp" (ARG6) \
    :           \
    );          \
})
```

However this code does not work, when I use it. Can someone help me out?

```
  char * readBuffer;
  MY_MMAP(readBuffer, 0, (sizeOfRead + 1),  PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1 ,0);
```

Here's the assembly code, made by gcc:

```
 movl %eax, %eax 
 movl $0, %ebx 
 movl %ecx, %ecx 
 movl $3, %edx 
 movl $34, %esi 
 movl $-1, %edi 
 movl $0, %ebp 
 int $0x80 
 mov %eax, %ebx
```

Comment: Excuse me, but what's wrong with calling `mmap` - it is a function that takes 6 arguments, why are you writing inline assembler to call it? It's also a quite expensive call, so bypassinc the C library to remove half a dozen instructions isn't exactly going to buy you a whole lot. And at least, try to explain WHAT isn't working.

Comment: I am experimenting on avoiding the use of libc. Just trying to improve my low level programming skills. And I don't know exactly what's wrong, I get a seg fault. I think it's something to do with moving information and types?

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembler. You are using EVERY register except for ESP, so I'm not surprised if the compiler messes that up. Avoiding libc is not a good goal!

Comment: added ASM code to the description

Comment: Using mov's like this in inline asm is almost always a mistake. Your constraints should have the values in the right registers upon entry to the asm statement.

Comment: Are you really running this under i386 linux?

Comment: I found the problem, but I don't know how to address it. Basically the syscall 90 takes in ONE argument of a struct with 24 bytes. But... there's only 5 registers I can use. Since eax is taken by the syscall argument number...

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer as the argument to the system call, it should be mmaps syscall number in eax before you do a int 0x80.

Comment: I don't think this is correct - you mean `x` is taken as a pointer? PTR is =r, which is %%0.

Comment: Yea, I purposely made an int x = 90 for the syscall.